# Why didn't I earn a Revival badge?

Tags: support, badges

My answer earned a [Necromancer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) (answer 60 days later, get a score of 5 or more) but not the [Revival badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival) (first answer 30 days later, get a score of 2 or more) even if it is [the only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675149/stitch-images-and-data-from-coupled-microscopy-spectroscopy-into-panoramic-in-ph/62870403#62870403).

Comment: There are 2 deleted answers on that question. The top rated answer on that question had a score of +4 before it was deleted. So yours was not the first answer scoring 2 or more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Revival badge also considers deleted answers. Because there is a deleted answer on that question, posted before yours and also have a score of at least 2, your answer is not eligible for the badge.

The Necromancer badge, on the other hand, does not care about any other answers on the question - it is based only on your answer.